# What algorithms do RDBMS use?

Tags: algorithm, rdbms

What are the main algorithms used in RDMBS ?

Comment: A DBMS is not a simple system. At the basic level, it will use B-Trees. I must say, your question is too wide. If you want, you could download mysql source code (I guess it is open source) to be able to understand - what it does & how?

Answer (score 4):

The most common is

B-Tree

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree

Answer (score 2):

A very complex topic.  B-tree is just one of the algorithms; it is a binary algorithm used to find records quickly.

Here are some others:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Database_algorithms

SQLite is a good database to study because the code base is very small and much easier to understand than the bigger ones.

Comment: SQLite sidesteps the whole concurrency issue that makes the bigger ones big. That might be a plus if you only want to know how the data lookup works. But to really understand modern databases you'll need to know what MVCC and write-ahead logging are.